# How to get another function's returned value?

Tags: vb.net, linq

How to give another function's returned value in LINQ.

I have a `IEnumerable` of `objects(Say ObjColl)`. From that object collection, I have to filter the objects based on the return value of another `function(say GetObjPropertyValue)`. My final output should be Dictionary of object and its propertyValue. This dictionary shouldn't have the objects for which propertyvalue is nothing.

`GetObjPropertyValue` function takes Object as input and return its property as string. But some times it returns nothing if that property not exist on Objects.

My query is something like,

```
Dictionary(obj, string)=ObjColl.Where(Function(p) not GetObjPropertyValue(p) is nothing)
```

but in above query I should write code to store the return value of GetObjPropertyValue(p) and add obj-p and returnValue combination to the dictionary. How to write that??

For Example See below code:

The last line below code is wrong. but please suggest me how to correct it. My intention is, I want output collection(say dictionary) of each fruitname and its color(returned by other function call) for all the fruits which the GetFruitColor is not nothing(it can be empty or valid string).

> [code] Private function GetFruitColor(fruit) as string
>         'It returns fruit color. 
>         'If valid fruit and color not available, it returns ""(empty string)
>         'If fruit is not valid Fruit, it returns nothing. End function

```
private sub MyMethod()
  Create a list of strings.
        Dim fruits As New List(Of String)(New String() _
                                {"apple", "passionfruit", "banana", "mango", _
                                 "orange", "blueberry", "grape", "strawberry"})

Dim query = _fruits.Where(Function(fruit) k= GetFruitColor(fruit) if not k is nothing select fruit, k) 
End Sub
```

In above code last line is wrong. So how to put getFruitColor in `k`, how to correct it to save the `k` value and give me output as dictionary of fruit and `k` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

- Project to an anonymous type consisting of (fruit, color)
- Filter out "nothing" colors
- Create dictionary

In C# this would be:

```
var query = fruits.Select(fruit => new { fruit, color = GetFruitColor(fruit) })
                  .Where(pair => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.color))
                  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.fruit, pair => pair.color);
```

Adjust accordingly for VB :)

Comment: Excellent answer Jon Skeet. It gives me correct solution. Thanks alot for your help.